# About numerOfSelfLoops(Graph G) p.523 in Algorithms by Sedgewick and Wayne,

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

I am reading *Algorithms* by Sedgewick and Wayne.

The following code computes the number of self-loops in an undirected graph G.

I cannot understand why this code returns **count/2** instead of **count**.

Please explain why.

p.523

```
public static int numerOfSelfLoops(Graph G)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
        for (int w : G.adj(v))
            if (v == w) count++;
    return count/2;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the algorithm finds the same loop twice so to speak. Loosely speaking once clockwise and once counter clockwise. The comment on the last line in the book is “each edge counted twice.”

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Marichyasana. I found addEdge(v, v) adds v to adj[v] twice (p.526). Thank you very much